# Como extrair Array de JSON para dentro de um atributo do tipo List de um objeto

Tags: java, lista, jackson, arraylist

Estou utilizando a API do Flickr para pegar as informações das imagens, o que retorna o seguinte JSON:

> {"photos":{"page":1,"pages":60,"perpage":100,"total":"5964","photo":[{"id":"21577339501","owner":"85277110@N02","secret":"31e850dfeb","server":"5785","farm":6,"title":"P1390956","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}, {"id":"21577287101","owner":"85277110@N02","secret":"412990658f","server":"611","farm":1,"title":"P1400012","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}, {continua os objetos da lista de json}]

Faço o seguinte código no controller do Spring para resgatar os objetos:

```
Collection<Photos> readValues = objectMapper.readValue(new URL(url), new TypeReference<Collection<Photos>>() { });
```

E retorna o seguinte erro:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Gostaria de saber como posso converter essa lista de objetos do atributo `photo` que está presente em `photos` para um `ArrayList`. Já procurei na internet por várias soluções e até agora não encontrei nenhuma.

Photos.class:

```
public class Photos {

    @JsonProperty("page")
    private Integer page;

    @JsonProperty("pages")
    private Integer pages;

    @JsonProperty("perpage")
    private Integer perpage;

    @JsonProperty("total")
    private Integer total;

    @JsonProperty("photo")
    @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = Photo.class, as = ArrayList.class)
    private List<Photo> photo;

    public Photos() {}

    public Photos(Integer page, Integer pages, Integer perpage, Integer total,
            List<Photo> photo) {
        super();
        this.page = page;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.perpage = perpage;
        this.total = total;
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public Photos(List<Photo> photo) {
        super();
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    public void setPage(Integer page) {
        this.page = page;
    }
    public Integer getPages() {
        return pages;
    }
    public void setPages(Integer pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }
    public Integer getPerpage() {
        return perpage;
    }
    public void setPerpage(Integer perpage) {
        this.perpage = perpage;
    }
    public Integer getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    public List<Photo> getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(List<Photo> photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}
```

Photo.class:

```
public class Photo {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Integer id;

    @JsonProperty("owner")
    private String owner;

    @JsonProperty("secret")
    private String secret;

    @JsonProperty("server")
    private Integer server;

    @JsonProperty("farm")
    private Integer farm;

    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("ispublic")
    private Boolean isPublic;

    @JsonProperty("isfriend")
    private Boolean isFriend;

    @JsonProperty("isfamily")
    private Boolean isFamily;

    public Photo() { }

    public Photo(Integer id, String owner, String secret, Integer server,
            Integer farm, String title, Boolean isPublic, Boolean isFriend,
            Boolean isFamily) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.secret = secret;
        this.server = server;
        this.farm = farm;
        this.title = title;
        this.isPublic = isPublic;
        this.isFriend = isFriend;
        this.isFamily = isFamily;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }
    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }
    public Integer getServer() {
        return server;
    }
    public void setServer(Integer server) {
        this.server = server;
    }
    public Integer getFarm() {
        return farm;
    }
    public void setFarm(Integer farm) {
        this.farm = farm;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Boolean getIsPublic() {
        return isPublic;
    }
    public void setIsPublic(Boolean isPublic) {
        this.isPublic = isPublic;
    }
    public Boolean getIsFriend() {
        return isFriend;
    }
    public void setIsFriend(Boolean isFriend) {
        this.isFriend = isFriend;
    }
    public Boolean getIsFamily() {
        return isFamily;
    }
    public void setIsFamily(Boolean isFamily) {
        this.isFamily = isFamily;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem diversas formas de deserializar este seu objeto usando Jackson, vou citar apenas duas delas, daí poderá escolhar a que acha mais adequada para usar no seu contexto.

Primeiro, considerando o JSON que informou, aparentemente o que você tem é um mapeamento errado. Neste trecho:

```
Collection<Photos> readValues = objectMapper.readValue(new URL(url), new TypeReference<Collection<Photos>>() { });
```

Você tenta obter diretamente uma coleção de `Photos`, mas segundo o JSON você não tem uma coleção deles, e sim um objeto qualquer, que tem um objeto `Photos` que só daí terá a lista de objetos do tipo `Photo`.

Então, novamente considerando este JSON:

```
{
   "photos":{
      "page":1,
      "pages":60,
      "perpage":100,
      "total":"5964",
      "photo":[
         {
            "id":"21577339501",
            "owner":"85277110@N02",
            "secret":"31e850dfeb",
            "server":"5785",
            "farm":6,
            "title":"P1390956",
            "ispublic":1,
            "isfriend":0,
            "isfamily":0
         },
         {
            "id":"21577287101",
            "owner":"85277110@N02",
            "secret":"412990658f",
            "server":"611",
            "farm":1,
            "title":"P1400012",
            "ispublic":1,
            "isfriend":0,
            "isfamily":0
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Para recuperar a lista de `photo`, vamos deserializar para um objeto qualquer, chamei de `OutsideObject`, que contém um objeto do tipo `Photos` e depois dele recupera a lista. As entidades ficaram assim:

- `OutsideObject`:

```
public class OutsideObject {

    private Photos photos;

    // getter e setter

}
```

- `Photos`:

```
public class Photos {

    private Integer page;
    private Integer pages;
    private Integer perpage;
    private Integer total;
    private List<Photo> photo;

    // getters e setters

}
```

- `Photo`:

```
public class Photo {

    private Long id;
    private String owner;
    private String secret;
    private Integer server;
    private Integer farm;
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("ispublic")
    private Boolean isPublic;

    @JsonProperty("isfriend")
    private Boolean isFriend;

    @JsonProperty("isfamily")
    private Boolean isFamily;

    // getters e setters

}
```

E o processo de deserialização ficou assim:

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

final OutsideObject outsideObject = objectMapper.readValue(json, OutsideObject.class);
final Photos photos = outsideObject.getPhotos();
final List<Photo> photoList = photos.getPhoto();
// faça o que quiser com photoList
```

Caso não queira criar este objetos "auxiliar" uma outra forma é usando a [*streaming API*](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi), neste caso iremos obter os nós até chegar a lista de `Photo`, será algo assim:

```
final JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
final JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(json);

// avança o stream até chegar no array
while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
    parser.nextToken();
}

final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

final List<Photo> photoList = objectMapper.readValue(parser, new TypeReference<List<Photo>>() {});
// faça o que quiser com photoList
```

Por fim, caso queira recuperar diretamente a lista, você pode também criar um [deserializar customizado](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Custom_Deserializers).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, irei tentar aqui, observei esse `photos`e pensei que com `@JsonRootName` resolveria, a ideia era mesmo criar um objeto contendo já a lista de fotos.

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian OK, qualquer coisa só avisar que se preciso atualizo a resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou aqui, somente com a instância de `OutsideObject` já da para manipular as informações tranquilamente. +1 e melhor resposta.