# Qual o problema dessa classe java que consome um serviço rest?

Tags: java, api, rest, servlet

Tenho um servlet :

```
import br.edu.ifpb.pos.model.Art;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ArtistaServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
//    https://api.vagalume.com.br/rank.php&type=art&radio=coca-cola-fm&apikey=660a4395f992ff67786584e238f501aa  
        String uri = "https://api.vagalume.com.br";
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget root = client.target(uri).path("rank.php");

        WebTarget comments = root.queryParam("type", "art")
                .queryParam("radio", "coca-cola-fm")
                .queryParam("apikey", "660a4395f992ff67786584e238f501aa");
        Response resp = comments.request().get();
        String json = resp.readEntity(String.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        List<Art> lista = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Art>>(){
        });
        lista.forEach(c -> System.out.println(c.name()));




            System.out.println(json);
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>API</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            for (Art art : lista) {
            out.println("<h3> " + art.name() + "   rank = "  +  art.rank() + "</h3>");            
            }
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
}
```

e essa interface :

```
package br.edu.ifpb.pos.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.immutables.value.Value;

@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableArt.class)
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableArt.class)
public interface Art {

    public String id();
    public String name();
    public String url();
    public String pic_small();
    public String pic_medium();
    public String uniques();
    public String views();
    public String rank();

}
```

Ja usei o mesma mesma logica  para consumir alguns serviços rest, porem com a [api da vagalume](https://api.vagalume.com.br/docs/rank/) não consegui captura a lista de artistas...
Aqui esta o projeto que possui essas classes no [github](https://github.com/WellingtonLins/ConsumindoeRest)

eis o erro:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: {"art":{"month":{"period":{"year":"2017","month":"12"},"all":[{"id":"3ade68b7g30dd1ea3","name":"Ed Sheeran","url":"https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/ed-sheeran\/","pic_small":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/ed-sheeran\/images\/profile.jpg","pic_medium":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/ed-sheeran\/images\/ed-sheeran.jpg","uniques":"208002","views":"366369","rank":"202.6"},{"id":"3ade68b7gb9e80ea3","name":"Demi Lovato","url":"https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/demi-lovato\/","pic_small":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/demi-lovato\/images\/profile.jpg","pic_medium":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/demi-lovato\/images\/demi-lovato.jpg","uniques":"189935","views":"281442","rank":"185.0"},{"id":"3ade68b7g3ea23ea3","name":"Kell Smith","url":"https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/kell-smith\/","pic_small":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/kell-smith\/images\/profile.jpg","pic_medium":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/kell-smith\/images\/kell-smith.jpg","uniques":"106449","views":"141385","rank":"103.7"},{"id":"3ade68b7g27d72ea3","name":"Thiago Matheus","url":"https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/thiago-matheus\/","pic_small":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/thiago-matheus\/images\/profile.jpg","pic_medium":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/thiago-matheus\/images\/thiago-matheus.jpg","uniques":"95219","views":"108237","rank":"92.8"},{"id":"3ade68b6g6b94fda3","name":"Can\u00e7\u00f5es de Natal","url":"https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/cancoes-de-natal\/","pic_small":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/cancoes-de-natal\/images\/profile.jpg","pic_medium":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/cancoes-de-natal\/images\/cancoes-de-natal.jpg","uniques":"93987","views":"244174","rank":"91.6"},{"id":"3ade68b5g1b38eda3","name":"Bruno e Marrone","url":"https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/bruno-e-marrone\/","pic_small":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/bruno-e-marrone\/images\/profile.jpg","pic_medium":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/bruno-e-marrone\/images\/bruno-e-marrone.jpg","uniques":"87188","views":"146422","rank":"84.9"},{"id":"3ade68b7gc8cb1ea3","name":"Anitta","url":"https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/anitta\/","pic_small":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/anitta\/images\/profile.jpg","pic_medium":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/anitta\/images\/anitta.jpg","uniques":"85509","views":"134193","rank":"83.3"},{"id":"3ade68b7gc2b03ea3","name":"1Kilo","url":"https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/1kilo\/","pic_small":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/1kilo\/images\/profile.jpg","pic_medium":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/1kilo\/images\/1kilo.jpg","uniques":"84077","views":"140543","rank":"81.9"},{"id":"3ade68b7g73521ea3","name":"Henrique e Juliano","url":"https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/henrique-e-juliano\/","pic_small":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/henrique-e-juliano\/images\/profile.jpg","pic_medium":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/henrique-e-juliano\/images\/henrique-e-juliano.jpg","uniques":"75953","views":"162824","rank":"74.0"},{"id":"3ade68b6g39a2fda3","name":"Jorge e Mateus","url":"https:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/jorge-e-mateus\/","pic_small":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/jorge-e-mateus\/images\/profile.jpg","pic_medium":"https:\/\/s2.vagalume.com\/jorge-e-mateus\/images\/jorge-e-mateus.jpg","uniques":"75295","views":"175375","rank":"73.3"}]}}}; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
```

Arquivo json da API do vagalume:

```
{
  "art": {
    "week": {
      "period": {
        "year": "2011",
        "week": "34"
      },
      "all": [{
        "id": "3ade68b7g98d71ea3",
        "name": "Bruno Mars",
        "url": "https://www.vagalume.com.br/bruno-mars/",
        "pic_small": "https://www.vagalume.com.br/bruno-mars/images/profile.jpg",
        "pic_medium": "https://www.vagalume.com.br/bruno-mars/images/bruno-mars.jpg",
        "uniques": "84709",
        "views": "183162"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Eu suspeitava que a minha estrutura inicial não estava de acordo com o json da API. Então comecei a mapear o arquivo json para classes java em meus testes, menos o tal do `Month`.    Ele não aparece explicitamente no json.
Como deduzir ele?

Comment: Coloque a sua classe `ImmutableArt`, por favor.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como extrair Array de JSON para dentro de um atributo do tipo List de um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91862/como-extrair-array-de-json-para-dentro-de-um-atributo-do-tipo-list-de-um-objeto)

Comment: @FelipeMarinho Essas classes são geradas automaticamente , tendo como parâmetro a interface Art

Comment: @FelipeMarinho  editei a pergunta e coloquei o link do projeto no github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O *schema* do JSON que você está tentando desserializar não corresponde à estrutura da interface que você montou. A sua interface `Art` corresponde um elemento do `array` chamado `all`, que não é o *root element* do documento JSON. `all` é uma propriedade de `month`, que é uma propriedade de `art`.

Você tem que criar as interfaces restantes:

#### Rank

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableRank.class)
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableRank.class)
public interface Rank {
    public Art art();
}
```

#### Art

Muder `Art` para:

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableArt.class)
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableArt.class)
public interface Art {
    public Month month();
}
```

#### Month

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableMonth.class)
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableMonth.class)
public interface Month {
    public Period period();

    public List<All> all();
}
```

#### Period

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutablePeriod.class)
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutablePeriod.class)
public interface Period {
    public String month();
    public String year();
}
```

#### All

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableAll.class)
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableAll.class)
public interface All {
    public String id();
    public String name();
    public String url();
    public String pic_small();
    public String pic_medium();
    public String uniques();
    public String views();
    public String rank();
}
```

### Fazendo a requisição

```
Rank rank = mapper.readValue(json, Rank.class);
rank.art().month().all().forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.name()));
```

Comment: muito obrigado , muito obrigado, Você ajudou muito... Tentei fazer o mesmo ontem , não com interfaces , mas com classes, java  entretando não tinha a classe Month como voce deduziu ela? Afinal, o java inclusive reclamava que não encontrava a tal classe.. Um abraço

Comment: @PenaPintada Pela propriedade `month` no JSON ;). Quando tiver alguma dificuldade tentando entender a estrutura do JSON, utilize um *json beautifier*, ou converta ele para classes Java com alguma ferramenta como [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

Comment: Grandes dicas, essas ferramentas. Eu conhecia apenas algumas a semelhantes ao json beautifier. Entretando, ainda estou pensando como foi  criado a classe Month.... Valeu cara!!!